# Erasing object from vector causes double free

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, copy-constructor

When i use vector of class B, which contains allocated memory, double free error occurs.

```
class B
{

public:
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    int *hehe;

    B()
    {
        a = "Hello";
        b = ", World!";
        hehe = new int[7];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            hehe[i] = i;
        }
    }

    ~B() {
        if (hehe)
            delete[] hehe;
    }
};
```

```
std::vector<class B> a(5);
    a.erase(a.begin() + 2);
```

Error message:

> a.out(46830,0x10e0015c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff12dc02a80: pointer being freed was not allocated
> a.out(46830,0x10e0015c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

And this code is working fine. I am stunned.

```
std::vector<class B> a(1);
a.erase(a.begin());
```

Comment: *I am stunned* -- Violation of the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  Go to the duplicate link, and go to the section marked **Managing resources**,  Does that example there look familiar?

Comment: In modern C++, it is pretty much unnecessary to use `new` or `new[]` (I haven't directly used either in the last 10 years).  Use the containers and smart pointer that manage the resources for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define the copy constructor or move constructor. So the same value of the pointer `hehe` is copied from one object to another object and the destructor frees the memory pointed to by the pointer `hehe` more than one time due to storing the same value of `hehe` in more than one object.

For example the copy constructor could be defined the following way

```
B( const B &b ) : a( b.a ), b( b.b ), hehe( new int[7] )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        hehe[i] = b.hehe[i];
    }
}
```

Also you need to define explicitly the copy assignment operator.